# reloadExtensionWithIdentifier is not working

Tags: blocking, ios10, callkit

When i try to add other number to call directory extension. It's not adding, i am taking the number from text filed and i try to add that number to call directory extension by using below method.

[contextIs addBlockingEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:phoneNumber];

After that i am calling below methods.

[contextIs completeRequestWithCompletionHandler:nil];

[[CXCallDirectoryManager sharedInstance] reloadExtensionWithIdentifier:@"com.something.something.CallIDExtension" completionHandler:^(NSError *error){
        if(error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"error is %@",[error description]);
        }
    }];

But it's not woking. I think reloadExtensionWithIdentifier is not updating the number to dictionary OR what i am doing wrong...

Comment: Are you able to post your full example source code or the Xcode project somewhere? One thing to check is that your extension's bundle ID matches the identifier you pass to `-[CXCallDirectoryManager reloadExtensionWithIdentifier:completionHandler:]`

Answer (score 0):

I got idea from your question, so I added reloadExtension on ViewController, and it did work!
So much appreciate you.